# Transparent, Click-Through Forms except custom Title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

i was picked some code, implement a Topmost, Transparent and Click-Though Form via code:

```
public enum GWL
{
    ExStyle = -20
}

public enum WS_EX
{
    Transparent = 0x20,
    Layered = 0x80000
}

public enum LWA
{
    ColorKey = 0x1,
    Alpha = 0x2
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, int crKey, byte alpha, LWA dwFlags);

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    int wl = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
    wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
    SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, 128, LWA.Alpha);
}
```

With this code, all of form are transparent and click-though absolutely (Text, image, control button...)

Current Form Border Style is none (no border, no title bar). Now I want to make a custom Title bar, allow user move Form to other position on screen (Like Title bar).

The problems here, all of form is cannot click on it (cause by click-though code), how to do the Click-though Form but except that custom Title Bar?

Custom title bar must be transparent as other element.
I don't want to keep original Title bar, it look bad for my application.

Comment: If the form is transparent how will the user know where the titlebar is??

Comment: Form is transparent, but user still see text and titlebar in form :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style means that you have to draw your form yourself with **only** the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function. You can still get all the messages from your controls, providing that you have already paint there with `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

`UpdateLayeredWindow` will draw an `hdc: handle device context` only, so if you want to draw an image:

```
IntPtr screenHdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr bmpHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(screenHdc);
IntPtr hBitmap; 

Bitmap bmp = .... //load your bitmap, a png one for transparency
hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));  //Zero: background is transparent
SelectObject(bmpHdc, hBitmap);

UpdateLayeredWindow(this.Handle, screenHdc, ..., ..., bmpHdc, ..., ..., ..., ...);
```

Take a look [UpdateLayeredWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information